# ¿Cómo calcular tiempo en PHP, cuando el formato es Datetime?

Tags: php

Estoy usando PHP para calcular el tiempo trascurrido entre dos *datetime*.

Estoy usando el siguiente código para descomponer las fechas y poder calcular:

```
$date1 = new DateTime($FechaInicio);
$date2 = new DateTime($FechaFin);

$diff = $date1->diff($date2);

echo ( ($diff->days * 24 ) * 60 ) + ( $diff->i * 60 ) + $diff->s . ' (S)';
```

Es correcto para encontrar los segundos pero no las horas in tente agregar los 60 min de la hora pero no los toma...

```
echo ( ($diff->days * 24 ) * 60 ) * 60 + ( $diff->i * 60 ) + $diff->s . ' (S)';
```

Como puedo acomodar esta cadena para que me arroje los años, dias , horas, minutos y segundo en segundos.

Comment: ¿Quieres total de segundos transcurridos entre las dos fechas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es posible que solo necesites formatear el resultado de la diferencia

```
<?php

$date1 = new DateTime("2020-01-01 10:01:05");
$date2 = new DateTime("2021-03-04 14:06:11");

$interval = $date1->diff($date2); // Retorna un objeto DateInterval 

echo $interval->format('%y año(s), %m mes(es), %d dia(s), %h hora(s), %i minuto(s), %s segundo(s)');
// resultado: 1 año(s), 2 mes(es), 3 dia(s), 4 hora(s), 2 minuto(s), 6 segundo(s)
```

Documentación del [DateInterval.format](https://www.php.net/manual/es/dateinterval.format.php)

Comment: Ok, es buen aporte me ayuda para ver como se descompone la fecha con las hora. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Es importante que las fechas que ingreses a Datetime($fecha) sean del formato correcto, de otro modo pueden darse resultados inesperados:

```
<?php
$date1 = new DateTime("2020-01-01 10:01:05");
$date2 = new DateTime("2021-03-04 14:06:11");
$diff = $date1->diff($date2);
print_r($diff);
?>
```

El resultado son 1 año, 2 meses, 3 dias, 4 hrs 5 min y 6 seg.

```
 ( [y] => 1 [m] => 2 [d] => 3 [h] => 4 [i] => 5 [s] => 6 ...)
```

Si solo te interesa el valor en segundos, puedes usar el calculo usando el tiempo en segundos de ambas fechas, obtenido con `strtotime()`:

```
<?php

$date1 = strtotime("2020-01-01 10:01:05");
$date2 = strtotime("2020-01-01 10:02:06");
$diff = $date2-$date1;
print_r($diff); // 61 segundos
?>
```

Comment: No había considerado el strtotime, te agradezco me sirve el dato.