# Como separa una hora superior a 24h?

Tags: php

Como puedo hacer para separa una hora que supere las 24. Normalmente se que se realiza asi

cuando total esta entre 00:30 a 23:30

```
$horas = date('H', strtotime($total));
$minutos = date('i', strtotime($total));
```

y los resultados seria

```
$horas = 23
$minutos = 30
```

eso sucede si uso el strtotime para esos casos.

Pero como haria cuando total supera ese limite cuando ya total vale 25:00 o 33:30 o 100:30
que usaria aqui

```
$horas = ;
$minutos = ;
```

Para que me arroje un valor asi

```
$horas = 33;
$minutos = 30;
```

Comment: Cómo quieres que regrese la información?

Comment: modifique la pregunta un poco

Comment: Saludos.Los formatos (al menos que conozco) de hora no están fuera de 00:00 a 23:59 (considerando en este ejemplo solo horas y minutos); si realizas algo como sumar estos, te sugerio los transformes a minutos; es decir que `$total` solo tengan minutos y al momento de presentarlo realices las operación para convertir a hora y minutos.

Comment: @RobertoLeOr propones una solución bastante buena y fundamentada, ¿qué tal una respuesta?

Answer (score 1):

Considerando que los horarios van de 00:00 a 23:59 (formato de 24hrs; para este ejemplo basandome solo en las horas y minutos); lo que debes tener en `$total` son minutos; es decir si tu origen/entrada de datos (según corresponda) fuese por ejemplo te pusieran 26 horas y 10 minutos: `26:10` tomar la parte de horas y convertirlas a minutos siendo estos **1560** minutos (de las horas) + **10** minutos para que tengas **1570** minutos; así por el estilo hasta; si fuesen te ingresan días sería el total de días (que te proporcionan) multiplicado por **24*60** para obtener **1440** minutos por cada día que te ingresen.

Observa que planteo convertir a minutos lo que procesaras, desde luego lo primero de 26 hrs y 10 minutos sabemos que es un día con 2 horas y 10 minutos, pero *"es como lo ingresan/tienes"* el caso es como corresponda convertirlo a minutos.

Así lo vas agregando en tu variable `$total`; considerando que `$total` tiene los minutos bastara realizar lo siguiente:

```
// Obtenemos el cociente
$horas = intdiv($total, 24);
// Obtenemos el residuo
$minutos = $total % 60;
```

Mira las guías de [intdiv](https://www.php.net/manual/es/internals2.opcodes.mod.php) y [%](https://www.php.net/manual/es/internals2.opcodes.mod.php) para mas consideraciones y Excepciones que se pueden generar para que las controles.

Con lo anterior puedes obtener mas de 24 hrs y los minutos de 00 a 59 (son 60 minutos).

Espero te sea de utilidad.

> La presente respuesta es en atención al comentario de @BetaM.

> Las consideraciones que menciono como te pasen días, horas minutos son en base a tu sistema como los recibes/obtienes y si permites días.

Answer (score 0):

Usando preg_split logre separar el formato de horas, horas y minutos

```
list($horas,$minutos) = preg_split('/[:| ]/', $total);
```

Ahora obtengo

```
$horas = 33; o cualquier otra hora que seupere el formato de 24
$minutos = 30,
```

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que buscas es una diferencia entre fechas, mira este ejemplo:

```
$date1 = new DateTime("2020-01-01 10:01:05");
$date2 = new DateTime("2021-03-04 14:06:11");

$interval = $date1->diff($date2); // Retorna un objeto DateInterval 

echo $interval->format('%y año(s), %m mes(es), %d dia(s), %h hora(s), %i minuto(s), %s segundo(s)');
// resultado: 1 año(s), 2 mes(es), 3 dia(s), 4 hora(s), 5 minuto(s), 6 segundo(s)
```

[Fuente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/391540/c%c3%b3mo-calcular-tiempo-en-php-cuando-el-formato-es-datetime/391581?noredirect=1#comment701517_391581).